# How animations like this are done...3d/artistic/cartoonish

Tags: animation, style-identification

the animation: http://vimeo.com/17535548

it's very much painted but it's 3dish...were all frames painted or some 3d software is capable of producing it...

Animation does look very fluid.

I am interested in learning to animate however not sure about which style to learn ...

---

A still from the video [from the creators' site](http://steakollective.net/meetbuck/):

[image]

Comment: Did you try contacting the team that created the video? I bet they'd love to clue you in!

Comment: 3D software creates the animation, and it and/or one or more rendering products can create the look...all with the helping hand of skilled illustrators and artists, of course.

Comment: They definitely are up for talking about their process - they responded to a couple of comments asking questions on Vimeo: in particular "`All the animated stuffs were made in 3D (with painted textures), but the backgrounds are in 2D.`", and "`we used 3DsMax for this production`". Why not ask them and direct them here? :) would love to see a more detailed description, it's a great style done really well

Answer (score 1):

Animations like that are usually made using [cel shading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading) combined with hand-painted elements. This effect is known for quite some time, occasionally it was used even in real-time rendered computer games (eg. Borderlands). Major difficulty usually comes in combining style of hand-drawn elements with 3D renders in a way where everything is consistent.

As for animation style - cel shading doesn't differ from anything else. It's just specific type of render. If you know how to correctly rig and animate character in cel shader - you know how to do it in any other render style. It's more about mastering 3D software then learning one specific animation style.